# How to a simple turn of the table (a pivot?) I can't seem to understand this simple concept

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query that returns a table of the form:

```
fastfill | slowfill
-------------------
    x    |     y
```

query:

```
Select fastfill, slowfill 
from cask_fills 
where barcode=xyz and gaugetype=xyz;
```

It will only ever return one record.

I need the query to instead return it in the form

```
 type    | fills
----------------
fastfill |   x
slowfill |   y
```

But I can't seem to work out how to use the pivot command to do this (or indeed any command to do this).

All the tutorials and examples i have seen have involved aggregate functions to group data which i do not need in this example and I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Rather an UNPIVOT. Simply do UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `UNPIVOT`

I would use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES` to make it.

```
select v.*
from cask_fills 
CROSS APPLY(VALUES ('fastfill',fastfill),('slowfill',slowfill)) v(type,fills)
where barcode=xyz and gaugetype=xyz;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8d48/1/0)**:

```
|     type | fills |
|----------|-------|
| fastfill |     x |
| slowfill |     y |
```

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
select 'fastfill' as type, fastfill as fill
from cask_fills 
where barcode=xyz and gaugetype=xyz
union all
select 'slowfill ', slowfill 
from cask_fills 
where barcode=xyz and gaugetype=xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone mentions UNPIVOT but noone posts the UNPIVOT query :

```
declare @cask_fills table (fastfill varchar(20),slowfill varchar(20))
insert into @cask_fills 
values
('x','y')

SELECT type,fills
FROM   
   @cask_fills p  
UNPIVOT (
          fills FOR type IN   (fastfill,slowfill)  
        ) AS unpvt;
```

The result is :

```
type        fills
fastfill    x
slowfill    y
```

The difference between `UNPIVOT` and the other answers is that `UNPIVOT` eliminates NULLs